# Heading Tag not Inheriting CSS attribute

Tags: css, inheritance, fonts, header

I have added a custom font for this code. I am trying to get my h1 tag to inherit the font-weight:bold; css attribute.

In my css I have added the font-weight bold in the body tag where it should affect all the text. I have also tried placing it in the h1 tag in css.

The font-weight is affecting everything but the h1 tag. What is going on?

```
@font-face {
    src:url(fonts/kohm.otf);
    font-family:'kohm';
}

body{
    background-color:silver;
    color:white;                               
    padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family:"kohm";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;


}

h1{
    background-color:#ffffff;                
    background-color: hsla(0,100%, 100%, 0.5);
    color:#64645A;                              
    padding:inherit;                               

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the question I found out that heading tags are already made bold so the font-weight:bold; attribute will not affect it. font-weight:normal; to un-bold it and adjust is font-size.

However when I am trying to italicize the font or make it oblique font-weight:italic; font-weight:oblique; it will not affect any of the text in the body paragraph. Why might that be?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong CSS syntax. You are using font-weight whereas you should be using font-style instead.

If you want to make the body paragraph italic, the correct syntax would  be

```
p {
font-style: italic;
 }
```

If you are trying to make it oblique, the correct syntax would be

```
p {
font-style:oblique;
}
```

I hope that helps!